# How to fire an event when a chrome tab is opened from command line?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i am opening a chrome tab from a command line, for example:

```
open -n -a 'Google Chrome' --args --profile-directory='Profile 35' 'http://localhost:3001/'
```

Its works fine. The tabs opened as expected. But i am creating a chrome extension that i need to execute an action to reload the page in case the chrome tab gets infinity loading.

Imagine you just executed that command line and the chrome tab was loading forever... i want to catch this moment. in my background.js i am listening to the onBeforeNavigate() event to start a countdown for a page reload. It works fine if i manually refresh the page, but doesnt get immediately executed if the page is opened from command line.

```
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener((details) => {
  console.log(details)

  if (
    details.frameType === 'outermost_frame' &&
    details.documentLifecycle == 'active' &&
    !details.url.includes('chrome://')
  ) {
    //execute some action
    //works fine if page is first updated manually
  }
})
```

You can ask why i am using onBeforeNavigate(), because i want to fire the countdown exactly after the user access a new url. It was the solution i could handle

I tried using onUpdated as well, but it didnt work. I dont know why events are not dispatched if the tab is not opened manually... Anyone could help me with this? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm shooting from the hip here, but it's possible that Chrome doesn't fire `onBeforeNavigate` (or any of the `webNavigation` sequence) for the page that loads on startup (command-line argument or default) because it doesn't consider that a "navigation."  Have you tried (1) wiring into [`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onBeforeRequest); (2) using a state variable in your extension to run the function if it hasn't already; or (3) using a query variable in the command-line URL, similar to (2)?

Comment: Extensions are started later than the active tab, so the event is not sent because it occurred beforehand. You can use chrome.runtime.onStartup event to start the timers on all currently open tabs.

Comment: @PhilN. Thank you, i had tried this solution and noticed webRequest is not available in manifest version 3. I found out the new approach wouldnt suit my case. But thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: try `chrome.tabs.query()` method in your `background.js` to check if the tab is still in a loading state after a certain time. If it is, you can then reload the page using the `chrome.tabs.reload()` method.